# Java Fx - How to populate a combo box with different data

Tags: javafx, combobox

My application it is a table and in the last column I have a combo box, but I need to populate it with different data taken from a database. For example first row will have a,b,c,d in combo box the second row will have e,f,g,h and so on. Each row will have different data in the list. If I put a list as I did now, I will have same values for each row which is not what I want. I also have an object called UpgradeDowngrade and the constructor is like this:

```
UpgradeDowngrade(boolean selected, String componentName, String version, List<String> firmwarelist) {
this.selectedComponent.set(selected);
this.componentName.set(componentName);
this.firmwareVersion.set(version);
this.firmwareList = firmwarelist;
}
```

I do not know how to accomplish this as my code looks like this for now:

```
  @FXML
private TableColumn<UpgradeDowngrade, String> firmwareVersion;

private ObservableList<String> firmwareList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    flashFirmwareVersion.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firmwareVersion"));
flashFirmwareVersion.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(flashFirmwareList));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319133/adding-values-to-selected-javafx-comboboxtablecell-dynamically/44330501#44330501. Check this if it helps you if doesn't, i will write the exact answer for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have cheked the link provided and the problem is that my catList is different from row to row ...

Comment: What do you mean different? Different in type or in content?

Comment: It's a little difficult to see what you intend here. What is the *value* that is represented by this table cell? A combo box has a pretty complex data model of its own: it has a list of items and a selected value, which is typically (but not necessarily) an element of the list of items. If the list of items is constant over the column, then the data represented by the cell is simply the selected item. But you would need the data represented by the cell to be an entire list, along with a selected value. You probably need to start by deciding how to represent that in the `UpgradeDowngrade` class

Comment: The list will be different in content and the content is taken dynamically from a database, i have tried to accomplish what i need by putting the last parameter as a List<String> .... The value that is represented by the cell is a String with a list behind it

Comment: Then you can use exactly the same structure that I have mentioned in that answer.Please read it again carefully.

Comment: My list is populated at runtime i do not know apriori what the list will contain like in the link you provided.

Comment: @AdrianaFrunza Ok, that explains the list (that part I understood), but what does the selected item in the combo box represent, in terms of the model? (Or, I guess, what do you want to happen when the user selects something in the combo box? What data in the model should change?)

Comment: @James_D: it represents a String

Comment: So how is it different to the question @Sunflame linked? That has a list of items which is part of the model (so only needs to be set when the model instances are created) and a string property represented the selected item.

Comment: Guys, sorry ... i was looking also at another example and i was mixing up things ... :(( But then I am not sure how can i set the list to the combo ..

Comment: I cannot understand the exact problem why you cannot set the items in teh comobBox.

Comment: OK. Please tell me how would you do it, maybe i will understand how to apply this example yo my case.

Comment: If you can open a chat and I'll explain it for you.

Comment: I have did it on my own, thanks a lot @James_D

Comment: Thanks a lot also @Sunflame